# Configuration setup : The "path" argument must be one of type[...] Received type undefined

Tags: nestjs

I followed along the [Configuration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration):

The module

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: new ConfigService(`development.env`),
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

The service:

```
export interface EnvConfig {
  [key: string]: string;
}
export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: EnvConfig;

  constructor(filePath: string) {
    console.log(filePath);
    const config = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
    this.envConfig = ConfigService.validateInput(config);
  }
[...]
```

whenever I run the app:

```
> nest start


development.env
[Nest] 10496   - 10/04/2019, 2:16:49 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
undefined
[Nest] 10496   - 10/04/2019, 2:16:49 PM   [ExceptionHandler] The "path" argument must be one of ty
pe string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined +14ms
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL.
Received type undefined
```

It seems the service is instantiated 2 times. I don't know why. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: And your `ConfigService` does only appear once in the `providers` array? No other module is providing it again? Can you show the module that is importing your `ConfigModule` resp. using your `ConfigService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounting to our discussion on discord, you are`providing` the `ConfigService` in your `AppModule` while **also** `importing` `ConfigModule` which leads Nest to think it needs to re-instantiate `ConfigService` but without the `filePath` variable for the constructor.

Removing the `ConfigService` from the `providers` array of the `AppModule` will resolve the problem.